# Can I disable control-C?

Tags: haskell, io

Is there a way to disable (temporarily) the interrupting effect of control-C in a regular running-in-a-shell Haskell executable?

Context: I have a little exercise which I set each year. It's a game where the students zipper around expressions triggering pattern matching rewrites as applicable, running in a shell window using hncurses. When the students have finished the last puzzle, they get an individual password which they need to send me. Being Windows veterans and Unix newbies, and of course (virtuously) lazy, they tend to select the password and type control-C. This has the unintended effect of interrupting the program and causing their password to vanish. The only way to recover it is to repeat the exercise. How cruel!

Whilst there are other ways I could work around the problem (e.g., printing a warning message or writing the password to a file), I'm curious to know if there's way to disable control-C.

Comment: I know this is a few years out of date, but you should be able to do something like what Ingo suggests from within your program, rewiring the user's terminal instead of installing a signal block. This strikes me as the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yep, you just have to temporarily ignore SIGINT:

```
import Prelude hiding (catch)
import Control.Exception
import Control.Concurrent
import System.Posix.Signals

-- Ensures the original handler is restored even after an exception.
--
-- installHandler returns the previous signal handler, so if you're
-- tied to some existing main loop, you could instead just keep
-- its return value around for later restoration.
ignoreSignal :: Signal -> IO a -> IO a
ignoreSignal sig = bracket (install Ignore) install . const
  where install handler = installHandler sig handler Nothing

pause :: IO ()
pause = threadDelay 2000000

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ignoreSignal keyboardSignal $ do
    putStrLn "Ctrl+C disabled."
    pause
  putStrLn "\nCtrl+C re-enabled."
  pause
```

(You can also write `keyboardSignal` as `sigINT` if you want to name it more directly.)

You could also replace `Ignore` with `Catch m`, where `m` is some action that prints guidance on the correct way to copy text. (Be careful, though; it'll run in a separate Haskell thread.)

Answer (score 8):

Quick and easy, use the shell:

```
stty intr ^T
run your haskell program here
stty intr ^C
```

This has the added benefit that programs can still be interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly catch the exception, which I believe is `UserInterrupt`:

```
handle (\exception -> do
     case fromException exception of
          Just UserInterrupt -> -- return to problem
          _                  -> error "unhandled exception") playWithStudents
```